# $g(x) = f(x)\sin(x)$ is bounded between $[0,∞)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Given function f Continuous in [0,∞).
$\lim_{x→∞} f(x) = L$

Prove that the function $g(x) = f(x)\sin(x)$ is blocked between $[0,∞)$.

I know that $\sin(x)$ is blocked and $f(x)$ has limit so -> blocked too
but is there a rule about arithmetic of blocked function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess you know how to do epsilon-delta proofs.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ existing implies for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $x>N\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In particular if $\epsilon = 1, |f(x)|\leq|f(x)-L|+|L|<1+|L|$.

This means that for all $x>N,f(x)$ is bounded. Now, $f(x)$ is also bounded in $[0,N]$ because you are in a closed interval. Therefore, for $x\in[0,\infty)$:

$$|g(x)| = |f(x)\sin(x)|\leq |f(x)|$$

Which you already know it's bounded. Therefore, $g(x)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin x $ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, so $|f(x) \sin x | \leq |f(x)|$.

Comment: So $g(x)$ bounded between $[0,f(x)]$ ?

Comment: No. $-f(x) \leq f(x) \sin x  \leq f(x)$. At $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k$ for integer $k$, you'll have $f(x) \sin x = f(x)$.  At $x=\frac{-\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k$ for integer $k$, you'll have $f(x) \sin x = -f(x)$. At $x=\pi k$ for integer $k$, you'll have $f(x)\sin x = 0$.

Comment: Ohhh... clearer. but if so, why they give the fact that $limx→∞f(x)=L$? we didn't use it

Comment: @motis10 Probably to show that the function isn't upper bounded.

Comment: If $f(x) \to L$ where $L \in \mathbb{R}$, then that means for any given $c>0$ there exists $x_c<\infty$ such that for all $x>x_c$, $f(x) \in [L-c, L+c]$. Then, since $f(x)$ is continuous, it has a maximum and minimum, $M, m$ in the closed finite interval $[0,x_c]$ (both of which are finite). Thus, $f(x)$ is bounded between $\max(L+c,M)$ and $\min(m,L-c)$.